# php rotator based on date and time

Tags: php, date, time

I found this script:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$time = date('H'); 
if($time < 12){ 
   echo 'good morning'; 
}else if($time >= 20 and $time < 21){ 
    echo 'good afternoon'; 
}else{ 
    echo 'good evening'; 
} 
?>
```

and would like to extend it to set it to specific dates and times, like:

- if time < 2011-11-30 13:59 echo 'before'
- else if time >= 2011-11-30 14:00 and < 2012-12-15 20:00 echo 'now'
- else echo 'after'

being a php noob, I looked all over the web, but the only examples I could find are either week days or hours but not the combination above. Could someone be so kind and help me get this set up?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use php's [mktime](http://php.net/mktime) function to create a unix epoch time from any date you want.

```
mktime(12, 34, 56, 7, 8, 2009);  // 12:34:56 on 7-8-2009
```

This can be then compared against [time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) which returns the current unix epoch.

```
$now = time();
$desired = mktime(12, 34, 56, 7, 8, 2009);
if ($now < $desired)
    echo "Not yet!";
else
    echo "It is past time!";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$time = new DateTime(); 
if($time < new DateTime('2011-11-30 13:59')){ 
   echo 'before'; 
}else if($time >= new DateTime('2011-10-31 14:00') and $time < new DateTime('2012-12-15 20:00')){ 
    echo 'now'; 
}else{ 
    echo 'after'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the input of the date() function, and the if conditions:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:m')); 
if($time < strtotime('2011-11-30 13:59')){ 
   echo 'Before'; 
}else if($time >= strtotime('2011-11-30 14:00') and $time < strtotime('2011-11-30 20:00')){ 
   echo 'Now'; 
}else{ 
   echo 'After'; 
} 
?>
```